# Stata - Change Order of Observations or Rows

Tags: sorting, row, stata

This is probably obvious, but I couldn't find it.  I want to move one row to a different place.  I know that one can `sort` rows in Stata.  I also know one can move around columns using `order`, but how does one order rows (when `sort`ing won't work)?  For example, I want to move row 4 before row 2:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

To get:

```
1
4
2
3
5
```

The pseudo code would be like:

```
order(_n==4), before(_n==2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem as posed seems artificial or indirect, but here is one way:

```
gen double obsorder = _n 
replace obsorder = 1.5 in 4
sort obsorder
```

No doubt that seems a bit awkward, but I don't think there is a more primitive or fundamental command to do this **given only your problem specification**. (Clearly 1.5 is only one solution: any value between 1 and 2 will work here.)

But why do I say the problem is artificial? You presumably have a reason for regarding observation 4 as being in the wrong position, so what is the reason? In Stata practice, I think one notices that observations are in the wrong order on some variable or combination of variables, so the answer is then simply to `sort` on that variable or variables.

If that isn't the answer, perhaps you could expand on your situation.

(Rows and columns are spreadsheet terms. Stata itself always talks of observations and variables in a dataset, unless matrices are being discussed.)

Comment: Thanks.  That should work.  It is actually not an artificial problem - basically the order matters in this application and I had to change the order around based on something not represented in a variable in my data.

Comment: That's a little obscure, but if your criterion isn't expressed in your data, then equivalently the solution can't be phrased neatly in terms of your data.

Comment: True - it's probably not worth explaining the details.  Thanks for the help.  Much appreciated.